# Как найти площадь пересечения двух прямоугольников?

Tags: c++, математика, геометрия, прямоугольники

Есть два прямоугольника стороны, которых параллельны осям и они пересекаются. Нам известно:

(x1,y1) - левая нижняя точка первого прямоугольника

(x2,y2) - правая верхняя точка первого прямоугольника

(x3,y3) - левая нижняя точка второго прямоугольника

(x4,y4) - правая верхняя точка второго прямоугольника

И нужно найти площадь их пересечения. Но пересекатся они могут с разних сторон.

Comment: @Igor просто у меня есть много прямоугольников которие нужно перебирать одни с другими. И не могу понять как найти площадь пересечения каждого с каждим. Как их перебратить и пересекаются ли они я знаю. А вот етого понять не могу. Так как ети прямоугольники могут пересекатся с разних сторон. Если знаете, то помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Можно для обоих найти общий прямоугольник, а затем умножить его ширину на высоту.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan да ну как найти нужное нам пересечение.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Хотя вопрос и простой, оставлю в качестве шпаргалки-сниппета:

```
#include <algorithm>

/*
    x1, y1 - левая нижняя точка первого прямоугольника
    x2, y2 - правая верхняя точка первого прямоугольника
    x3, y3 - левая нижняя точка второго прямоугольника
    x4, y4 - правая верхняя точка второго прямоугольника
*/
int f(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int x4, int y4)
{
    int left = std::max(x1, x3);
    int top = std::min(y2, y4);
    int right = std::min(x2, x4);
    int bottom = std::max(y1, y3);

    int width = right - left;
    int height = top - bottom;

    if (width < 0 || height < 0)
        return 0;

    return width * height;
}
```

Исходя из вопроса, полагаю, что координаты растут из нижнего левого угла (если же Y растет сверху вниз, то необходимо внести соответствующие поправки).

Идея простая, иллюстрируется на картинке (показано как определяется ширина общего прямоугольника, высота определяется аналогично):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Visual Studio подчеркивает max(), а с min() все ок

Comment: После появления картинки хочу проголосовать "за" еще раз.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan что делать когда подчеркивает только max(), а min() нет

Comment: @OlexijHavryshkiv Напишите свою функцию `max`.

Comment: *Начало координат обычно буквой O обозначается, а не двумя ноликами*

Comment: @PavelMayorov я прогуливал Декарта Евклидова ))

Comment: @OleksiiHavryshkiv По поводу "Visual Studio подчеркивает max()" https://stackoverflow.com/a/2789509/6547185